# Is there a tag for questions about optional uses of "that"?

Tags: discussion, tag-request

Many sentences include the word "that".  In Standard English, there is a category of situations where the word "that" makes the sentence slightly clearer, but the word "that" is optional.  For example, the following question is about an optional "that":

[where the suffix indicates the address is part of... -- is this grammatically correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110623)

Is there a tag for questions about optional uses of "that"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a a form of [tag:ellipsis]?

Comment: [tag:subordinators]